# Django 2 versions of german

Tags: django

I'm developing website with 2 versions of german (Default and Austrian).

My problem is that template do not differ them, so in select django displays them both as Deutsch(de).

Languages in settings.py:

```
('en', _('English')),
('de', _('German')),
('de-at', _('Austrian'))
```

template code:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
                            <select style="border:1px dotted black" name="language">
                              {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                              {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                              {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                              {% for language in languages %}
                             <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                             </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                             <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Change' %}" />
                    </form>
```

Code is from documentation.

Translation in Austrian language doesn't work, because django in select defines Austrian as default Deutsch select it and do not translate.

So, are there any ways to display sublanguage in template, like (Deutsch(de-at)) or just (Austrian instead of Deutsch), or are there any other ways to solve it?

Tried to change all languages in settings:

```
('en-us', _('English')),
('de-de', _('German')),
('de-at', _('Austrian'))
```

Then created .po and .mo files to them. But still template defines them as same languages. Also I thought about changing language name in template, but as far as I understand I can't do it.

Comment: You did provide a translation in the de-at po right? Is `USE_I18N=True`? What happens if you change `LANGUAGE_CODE='de-de'` to `LANGUAGE_CODE='de-at'`. Do you see your translations?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't answer earlier:). In settings.py everything is ok: i18n - true, localemiddleware, and contextprocessor. I can't change from de-de to de-at because django defines this two languages as equal, so when I change from english to german it always defines de-at, and if I try to change to de-de it again change to de-at, but translates as de-de.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sold my problem, still don't understand what's the reason...
Django front end form, that I copied from documentation doesn't work as it should.

Form, that I used on front side works correct only with base languages and crashes on sublanguages(all). Now I've rewrite this form:

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <select style="border:1px solid black" name="language">
            {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                <option value="{{ lang.0 }}"
                    {% ifequal lang.0 request.LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                        selected="yes"
                    {% endifequal %}
                >{{ lang.1 }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Change' %}" />
    </form>
```

Per now it works fine...